# accessing php array in js using json_encode

Tags: php, javascript

I am using php and JS in my code.My requirement is I need to fetch the value from my-sql database and display into drop down list dynamically.I am populating the dropdown with JS but fetching the value with php(a usual thing).
So the problem I am facing is once I get the value from php code and encode it using json_encode to access that array in JS it shows me value like [object Object].

Please help..
Thanks.

Sample Code:-

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("select Location from servicelist")or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 $output[]=$row;
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$output[]=$row;

 ?>
<script language="javascript">
function addOption_list(selectbox){
<?php echo 'var month='.json_encode($output);?>

for (var i=0; i < month.length;++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.AreaList, month[i], month[i]);
//Once the value of the area will get selected we will call sub area based
//on the area selected from the db
}
addSubAreaList();
}
```

Comment: show us the generated code (post PHP execution)

Comment: Hi Janus,

Please check the edits in the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript are similar to "associative arrays" in PHP. If you have an object and you try to write it on the console, it will evaluate to the string "[object Object]". If you want a proper string representation, JSON encode it again in your JavaScript using JSON.stringify.

Comment: I tried var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
So what should be that replacer??
And if I try the replacer as a string it doesnot work..

Comment: the replacer is optional, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: How do we got that PHP array into a JS array here?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` returns an associative array, so your `month` variable in JavaScript will be in the format:

```
var month = [{field: 'value', otherField: 'value'}];
```

your loop therefore needs to use something like:

```
var areaList = document.drop_list.AreaList;
for (var i=0, len = month.length; i < len; ++i){
  addOption(areaList, month[i].field, month[i].otherField);
}
```

Comment: It worked..
The only thing I was missing was the column after the month field of which I need to fetch the value.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: No problem, re-reading your PHP, the query is only picking out one field, so you could make it simpler by using `$rows = mysql_num_rows($result); for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) $output[] = mysql_fetch_result($result,$i,0);` then the `month` variable in the JavaScript would be a string array, so you could use the JavaScript you originally had.